# Legend Title color: sns python

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, legend, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to use the Py script in Power BI so I can display some graphs but I need it to blend with the theme. I've managed to change some of the colors already (bg, text etc) but I'm now missing one single piece (red mark on image) and I can't find the code to change it.

So far I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# Set the background color
sns.set(rc={'ytick.labelcolor':'#FFFFFF','xtick.labelcolor':'#FFFFFF', 'legend.labelcolor': '#FFFFFF', 'axes.labelcolor': '#FFFFFF', 'axes.facecolor':'#283D56', 'figure.facecolor':'#283D56'})
sns.pairplot(dataset[["Average Duration","Age", "Gender"]], diag_kind="hist", hue="Gender")
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Please explain what you mean by `Red mark on image`?